# CSRF verification failed with using model

Tags: python, django

i am not using any template i am just making a model and my model code is

```
from django.db import models

class cmdr(models.Model):
    text=models.TextField()
```

my browser cookies is enable

now when i am trying to login in admin panel its giving me CSRF verification failed
i am not making any templates right now. i am studing django from online its working good in my instructor machine but not in my laptop 
my cmd showing this

```
[27/Oct/2018 09:35:22] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[27/Oct/2018 09:35:22] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1819
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[27/Oct/2018 09:35:23] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1974
[27/Oct/2018 09:35:23] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1819
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /admin/login/
[27/Oct/2018 09:35:36] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
[27/Oct/2018 09:35:36] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1819
[27/Oct/2018 09:41:35] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1819
[27/Oct/2018 09:42:06] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1819
[27/Oct/2018 09:49:58] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1819
[27/Oct/2018 09:52:51] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1819
```

Comment: can you show the traceback?

Comment: can you tell me what is traceback and how should i get that i am totally new in django

Comment: traceback is the same that errors shown from the console or in the explorer

Comment: i had added it in my question please have a look

Comment: did you add the `{% csrf_token %}` tag in your template?

Comment: that;s what i am saying i don't have any template

Comment: @vivekmodi can you share your settings.py file after removing any sensitive information, something is probably wrong there

Comment: also you can try clearing your browsers cookies

Comment: my code is working properly in my friend laptop

Comment: Your cmdr seems fine, but {% csrf_token  %} is missing in your login template. How you are using login, can you share?

Comment: my code is working good in my pc firefox browser but not in chorme